# Python3 module Installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, aiohttp

I'm trying to install the module aiohttp for python so I can set up a system for downloading files with uvloop. I'm having some difficulty, though, when I go into my folder which I extracted aiohttp to and doing the following commands:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, Extension
ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

I looked around and saw that some people had this problem but it was fixed by getting the python-setuptools or python3-setuptools package. So I tried to do that but this is the output I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-setuptools is already the newest version.
python3-setuptools set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-setuptools is already the newest version.
python-setuptools set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

Which leads me to believe that python-setuptools is already installed! I'm not sure where to go from here. Just for clarity, I did try

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

but I received an error because Python 3.4.1+ is needed to install aiohttp:

```
sudo python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 61, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.1+")
RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.1+
```

I'm running Linux Mint 17.2 Qiana on an HP Elitebook 8440p. Any suggestions as to what I should do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure `apt-get install python3-setuptools` is doing it for the same python version that python3 refers to? Have you tried `pip3 install setuptools`?

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly! Here's the output I get for that command: (I can't figure out how to get this stuff not inline.... help?)
`sudo pip3 install setuptools

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages

Cleaning up...`

Comment: in that case try just running `python3` and in the interactive session try to `import setuptools`, if that fails be sure to see the version with `import sys ; print(sys.version)`

Comment: `import setuptools` was unable to find a module named setuptools. `import sys ; print(sys.version)` printed '3.5.1 (default, May 4 2016, 16:26:46) [GCC 4.8.4]'

Comment: so one is using 3.4 and the other was using 3.4, so just use `pip3.5 install setuptools` and then `python3.5` to make sure they are the same version.

Comment: pip3.5 isn't installed... How do I install this version of pip?

Comment: you can refer to https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ for installing pip.

Answer (score 2):

First Install python3

`brew install python3 && cp /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`

Then use pip3 to install aiohttp

`pip3 install aiohttp`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dnf install python-devel-2.7.12-6.fc24.x86_64` solved my problem

Comment: I think it was because I was using the python command, not python3.

Answer (score 0):

For me installing uvloop worked, working on Mac laptop:

```
  pip install uvloop
```